# Is there a galactic "goldilocks" region in the galaxy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, astrophysics, astronomy, space

I'm wondering if there's a region where the star density in the galaxy create the conditions in outer space where the galactic temperature is between 0 and 200°F. This may cause a ring shaped where liquid water exist in interstellar space. This is question comes from the fact the center of the galaxy is around 1,000,000K while out here we are around 2-8K. So i came to the hypotheses going inward it will gradually get warmer until its too hot to handle.

I have wondered this for years but cant find information about it.

Comment: Generally physics stack exchange gets plenty of questions that could have also gone to astronomy stack exchange, and they get good answers. This question, however, would really be much better on astronomy stack exchange. It really is purely an astronomy question and not a question about physics principles.

Comment: The interstellar medium is at a very low pressure, so you would need very low temperatures in order to have liquid water.

Comment: The pressure of the interstellar medium is below the "triple point" of water, so interstellar water can be solid or gas but not liquid. I recall reading about a "galactic Goldilocks zone" in the past, but it was about having few enough stars for planetary systems to be long-term stable, while having enough cold gas for star formation. I do not have a reference, unfortunately.

Comment: @Javier I presume this asker means if there was a planet with no home star or with a dead/far away home star so that its temperature came from the galactic center. Just like the goldilocks region in the solar system does not mean that liquid water droplets are floating around between Earth and Mars.

Comment: This is much better suited for Astronomy.SO indeed. To begin with, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_habitable_zone and watch https://youtu.be/v4ogRCjhFDM and https://youtu.be/M7PM8iDt_4w. As you see, it's related to the structure of a particular—in this case, our—galaxy, or any one similar enough. Some generalisations do apply indeed, many galaxies are similar, but the differences aren't fundamentally astrophysical. @rob, as a mod, if you have the majick mojo to move this Q to Astronomy, would it be much trouble, wouldn't it?

Comment: There may be a galactic Goldilocks zone but it has nothing to do with the reason you suggest. Liquid water cannot exist in interstellar space.